# Audio pauses when Soundcloud html5 widget becomes hidden by jQuery

Tags: jquery, html5-audio, soundcloud

Regarding [THIS](http://cosystudios.com/thecosystudio.co.uk/thecosystudio.html) site

### Brief Synopsis

Clicking on the *Listen* tab on the left reveals a soundcloud player (several in fact, within a scrollable pane)
Click on play and inspect that closing the panel (using jQuery hide() method) also stops the audio.

From what I knew of the hide() method, the objects are only hidden and not destroyed. Using firefoxs inspector, this seems to be true since i can still view the instance of the soundcloud player after hiding. So why does audio pause?

### Used code

The jquery that currently affects the 'drawer'

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            $(".sctrigger").click(function(){
                $(".scdrawer").toggle("slow");
                $(this).toggleClass("active");
                return false;
             });
            $("#scMain").scrollable({
                  vertical: true,
                 keyboard: 'static',
  }).navigator("#scNavi");
```

### Goals

I'd like to not interupt playback open when closing the slideout panel.

Additional functionality, it would be nice however to call on the player and display the track name&artist and a *stop* button within the *'listen'* tab that remains on the page when closed

### Potential solutions

If the player is being destroyed ,is there a jquery method that could hide the player and not remove it entirely?

I have a feeling one solution would be to embed the player code within the page and use the soundcloud api to call on functions using my own icons etc, but this is a lot of build time especially considering my unfamiliarity and minimal experience..when I'm quite satisfied with the html5 widget.

Regarding the additional functionality; can one use any java based calls on the widget to get track info?

This is my first post so apologies if I'm not following standards & a huge thanks ahead to the community out there on SO. Love this site.

Comment: Possibly able to test whether drawer is shown & Player is in play mode and re-call play function if true?

Comment: Thanks Nick for your detailed analysis & reply. I see what you mean, Int explorer doesn't cause the same issue. Perhaps jQuery was just busy or I had too many tabs open. I will test this furthur as the site progresses. So to clarify on the track data front, I would create a var using var $trackname = SC....getCurSound and then $append() this data to a specified div within the tab? I'll have a play and see where it gets me. Thanks,

Comment: So I managed to draft up the following code:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't recreate the error (Chrome 19, Firefox 13 on Ubuntu): playback continues fine even with rapid clicks on the 'Listen' tab.

jQuery.hide indeed does just hide whatever container element you specify and doesn't touch any of the child nodes, so they're definitely not being destroyed.

Is it pausing permanently, or does it just cause a momentary break in playback? If the latter, perhaps part of the issue might be the extra processing the browser has to do to perform the hiding animation is blocking the audio playback? This would be a bit surprising since I've never seen javascript/rendering affect media playback before. You could test this by removing the animation from the hide to see if that changes anything.

In terms of grabbing the track info, or controlling the playback via your own calls, you can use the [widget API](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/html5-widget#). To get track information (that is, the data as described in the [API docs](http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/reference#tracks), like title, artwork url, user name, etc), you can use `SC.Widget(...).getCurrentSound()`

Comment: Thanks Nick for your detailed analysis & reply.

I see what you mean, Int explorer doesn't cause the same issue.

Perhaps jQuery was just busy or I had too many tabs open.

I will test this furthur as the site progresses.

So to clarify on the track data front, 
I would create a var using var $trackname = SC....getCurSound
and then $append() this data to a specified div within the tab?

I'll have a play and see where it gets me.

Thanks,

Comment: #Results from additional questions#